# Introducing Team Foundation Server into a FogBugz based team: Which features to use?

Tags: tfs, fogbugz

I currently work in a company that uses FogBugz for issue and bug tracking and SourceGear Vault for source control.

We are now introducing Team Foundation Server. Clearly TFS will replace Vault for source control. My question is, with the following requirements:

- Large existing base of FogBugz cases (some obviously open) that we need to support ongoing
- Support desk needs to be able to raise bugs / support calls
- Want changes to source to be linked to a case number

... what is the best split between using FogBugz cases and TFS WorkItems?

- Is it possible to totally migrate from FogBugz to TFS?
- If it is not possible to migrate from FogBugz to TFS then what is the best way to use the FogBugz case and TFS workitems together?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Initially I'd say bugs and defects stay in FogBugz, stuff on the project plan as work items. You could manually get the developers to create a work item for each case in FogBugz and associate the code with that work item but I can hear the howls of derision already :-)

You might want to take a look at the [TFS Integration platform](http://tfsintegration.codeplex.com/). I don't know if there are any tools that link directly to FogBugz but these tools are highly extensible. You could then decide to either migrate everything in to TFS or run both systems and synchronise. Running both is nice as each discipline can use the tool they are most familiar with, devs use TFS for everything and the testers / support can continue to use Fogbugz and the toolkit keeps everything in step.